# app compat dependency got error when i added google play dependency

Tags: android, firebase, dependencies

I was building an app using firebase in the android studio. when I added the google play dependency, my app compat dependency got an error.

**here is my gradle**

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'


compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.2.1'


 compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.1'


compile 'com.android.support. :constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha9'


 compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:10.0.1'


 compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'


compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'


compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.3.+'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.1'
```

Comment: Try use latest versions of support libraries

Comment: Your posted dependencies include both `play-services:10.0.1` and `play-services:10.2.1`.  Remove `play-services:10.2.1`.

Comment: Always make sure all your Firebase and Play Services dependencies match versions.  The latest version is 10.2.1 at the time of this writing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First - Add google services dependency in **project-level** build.gradle file.

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files

        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
```

Second - In **app-level** build.gradle file, add various dependencies you want to use in your app such as appcompat, recyclerview, cardview, firebase, etc and then apply the play service plugin at the bottom in the build.gradle file as shown in the code below.

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'

    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:10.2.1'
    }

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

finally Build your project. Hope it helps :)